# What am I doing wrong here - setTimeout on document load

Tags: javascript, facebook, function, document-ready

Are working with an app and need to execute the function postCook after 10s but something is wrong. Just worked with Javascript / jQuery for a couple of day's so still not flooowing :)

But have now been stuck on this for several hours so even if it breaks my heart i need to ask for advice

```
$(document).ready(function() { setTimeout("postCook", 10000);
};

  function postCook()
  {
  FB.api(
  '/me/app:action',
  'post',
  { game: '<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>' },

function(response) {
if (!response || response.error) {
alert('Error occurred');
} else {
alert('Successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
}
    });
         }
```

Can execute it with button without problem so 100% sure that it's within setTimeout

Comment: You're also missing the closing `)` at `.ready(function() {...};` -> `.ready(function() {...})`

Comment: Thanks, That was what i was missing all the time, Works like a charm now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the quotes. `setTimeout(postCook,5000)`. NEVER pass a string to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks, Did without it also during this hours, The main thing was missing the ")" Will accept your answer 

Thanks @andreas

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you never call the function. The code in the string just gets the reference to the function and does nothing with it. This would work:

```
setTimeout("postCook()", 10000);
```

However, as you have a reference to a function, you should use that directly instead:

```
setTimeout(postCook, 10000);
```